# Getting layer attributes along path between two points in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, point, attribute-table, polyline-creation

In QGIS I have a map of source [square] and receptor points [circles], see map. I also have a layer with ground-type data (Corine Land Type 2018). I want to know how the ground type changes along straight-line paths from the source point to each receptor point. I can't find any solutions for obtaining layer attributes along paths between two points.

The application is for a sound propagation prediction program which needs information on the ground type along the source-receptor paths. It would be then helpful to have some array with land type vs distance between the two points. How can I do this? Also if there's a way to batch-perform this operation in Python that would be useful.

[image: See map]

Comment: You need to limit your question to either QGIS tool or python.

Answer (score 4):

One solution that doesnt require your raster to be converted to polygons:

1. [Densify by interval](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgisdensifygeometriesgivenaninterval) with your line layer as input. Set the interval to whatever distance you want to sample raster values as.
2. [Extract vertices](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgisextractvertices) to create points along the lines.
3. Field Calculate a new column in the output with the formula below. Each point will get the value of the pixel beneath it.

`raster_value(layer:='landuse', band:=1, point:=$geometry)`

(I dont know what you want to do next.)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. Create the paths. Run the [Geometry by expression](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgisgeometrybyexpression) tool, set as **Input layer** the **source** layer, set the **Output geometry type** as lines and set the **Geometry expression** to the following expression.

   ```
   aggregate(
       'source layer name/id', --replace here with your layer name/id
       'collect',
       make_line($geometry, geometry(@parent))
   )
   ```
2. now you'll have a MultiLine geometry layer connecting each source with each receptor. Convert this result to LineString geometry type, use the [Multipart to singleparts](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#multipart-to-singleparts) algorithm.
3. Polygonize the raster running the [Polygonize](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/rasterconversion.html#gdalpolygonize) tool. The pixel values will be stored by default in a field called **DN**, this field name will be required in the last step.
4. Use the following expression to calculate a new text field in the resulting layer of step 2, this text will store the array with the information of what landcover thus a line crosses and the distance. It could be a long text so set the length to a considerable length (512).

   ```
   array_to_string(aggregate(
       layer:='Polygonized layer name/id', -- set here the poligonized layer name/id
       aggregate:='array_agg',
       expression:="Landcover category field name" || ': ' || length(intersection( -- set inside double quotes the field name where you stored the landcover info in the step 3.
           $geometry,
           geometry(@parent)
       )),
       filter:=intersects(
           $geometry,
           geometry(@parent)
       )
   ))
   ```

**Notes**:

*All the layers must be in the same CRS*

*The array will be a key value pair where keys are the land cover codes and the values will be the lengths (`cat1: length1, cat2: length2`, catn: lengthn)*

*Length will be returned in the project CRS units*

Answer (score 2):

If you create actual line features you can use the [intersect tool](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vector_overlay_tools.html) to split those lines using the polygons.

Once the lines are split you can populate the lines with the polygon attributes using a spatial join.  [Here is a tutorial on a spatial join](https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/performing_spatial_joins.html).

The attribute table of the resulting spatial join would have a row for each line segment and a column for each data value - thus the array you desire.

Populating that table with distances or lengths should get posted to another question.  So should question about [automating these steps with Python](https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/getting_started_with_pyqgis.html).